# java join elements in array

Tags: java, arrays, join

Suppose I have an int array:

```
intarray = [2,3,5,7,8,8,9,3...]
```

how to join the first 5 elements there or others?

for instance, I would have the numbers `23578` or `35788` or `57889`...?

I'm trying to do it because I need to compare the numbers with each other

by the way, I'm still looking for great source that keep all docs about java language

Comment: Your documentation search can start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/), if you didn't try it already.

Comment: What have you tried? Here is the current [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) and the current [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). Also, your task can be accomplished fairly easy by multiplying by 10.

Comment: I do not just know, which method a should use here, I found methods that help join arrays rather than elements into the only one array

Answer (score 2):

```
pseudocode:

    int frstNumber = 0;
    for i = 0 to 4
         firstNumber *= 10;
         firstNumber += array[i];

    nextNumber = firstNumber
    for i = 5 to end of array
         nextNumber = (nextNumber mod 10000) * 10 + array[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intarray = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 3 };

    for (int j = 0; j < intarray.length - 4; j++) {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = j; i < j + 5; i++) {
            s = s + String.valueOf(intarray[i]);
        }
        int value = Integer.parseInt(s);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
23578
35788
57889
78893
```

Comment: exactly, then I would make all of the possibility variants, in your case the output data should be: 23578, 35788,57889,78893

Comment: hm, It's a bit strange, It doesn't work properly, you know. for example, if we consider a string "String ="731637176513306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352";" we'll get a 6249 number among all values

Comment: @user1813163 What you mean?  We are using Array here not String.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't to insert a code in my comment correctly, I didn't get hot to insert my code in order to it will easy to read ;(

Comment: @user1813163 6249 is integer before 6 there is 0 so it prints 6249. If you want o print "06246" you can by directly print s.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a library, and work at a higher level, try [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

```
    int[] ary = {7,4,1,2,5,8,9,3};
    Iterable<int[]> first5 = Iterables.limit(Lists.newArrayList(ary), 5);
    String joined = Joiner.on("").join(first5);
```

See [Iterables.limit()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
StringUtils.join([1, 2, 3], null) = "123"
```

[from apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28int%5B%5D,%20char%29)